# Keras neural network model doesnot return the same prediction at android code like as at python code after trainig

Tags: python, android, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Next several my action I hope get a good prediction at the my android app:

1. I have trained the model like that guide [Keras Tutorial: How to get started with Keras, Deep Learning, and Python](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/10/keras-tutorial-how-to-get-started-with-keras-deep-learning-and-python/)!
   [image: my model keras]

My input data is(bitmap 32*32*3):
[image: data were been insert:]

After teach I make a test predict(for my test picture) at python and get predicion 93%.
[image: prediction between 3 classes:]

2. Convert it from ht5 to tflite

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
```

3. Try to use it an android app
   I have used the same data (byte array 32*32*3)
   [image: data were been inserted at]

And code work without any errors:

```
tflite.run(data, labelsArray);
```

but I get as output:
[image: output prediction]

Its not a 93% at all!

I tried to reconvert NN, but the same result.

**Update 22.10.2019: But thean I have rewrite android application more simple way - and its worked! Suppose it was a bug at my code.**

Comment: Could you point to more details about how you are performing inference on Android? Assuming the model has converted correctly, there might be issues with what data the model is actually receiving.

Comment: The columns of numbers, that I paste as arrays(32*32*3) that is the particular array (data), which I set as parameter twice:

Comment: at first for get control predict after teaching NN and second - at the android "tflite.run". As we can see - its have the same data. But thean I have rewrite android application more simple way  - and its worked! Suppose it was a bug at my code.